# Thingworx: GET method not allowed

Tags: thingworx

Here in [tutorial](http://support.ptc.com/cs/help/thingworx_hc/thingworx_6.0_hc/index.jspx?id=thingworx10&action=show) is written:

> The following API call executes the service GetBlogEntriesWithComments
>   that is associated with the Thing called
>   ThingWorxTrainingMaintenanceBlog.
>   `http://localhost/Thingworx/Things/ThingWorxTrainingMaintenanceBlog/Services/GetBlogEntriesWithComments`

By this example I created `Thing` **CarA** and I want to call default `service` but I get 405 error code 'not implemented'

```
http://localhost:8080/Thingworx/Things/CarA/Services/GetProperties
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `POST` request, dude:

```
curl -v --basic --user name:pass -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8080/Thingworx/Things/CarA/Services/GetProperties?Accept=application/json
```